# Android "Voice input" option in settings is missing

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have two cheap Android phones, both MediaTek chipset. First is Android 5.1 - in Language & Input settings I see "Voice input" and "Voice control" options and speech recognition works. Second phone is Android 6.0 and I don't see "Voice input" option there:

[Photo of both phones side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUIO0.jpg)

When I call

```
SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(activity)
```

it returns true but speech recognition doesn't work (I don't even hear that "ding" to start talking). What I need to install to get voice control on the second phone? I have tried TalkBack and Gboard (in which voice recognition works fine). Any ideas? Also when I show intent to choose Voice input service:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_VOICE_INPUT_SETTINGS), 0);
```

it works on both phones (It shows Assist & voice input). I can choose assist app (google or none), neither enables voice input. I can set Voice input to Basic google recognition (just like on first phone) but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Google app and Google now launcher and it works now.